# Why are my Sassy CSS styles not being applied? Receiving MIME Type Error with Scss in Chrome Dev tools

Tags: apache, sass, zurb-foundation, mime-types

This is my first time working in serious web dev and using Foundation.

**

### Questions:

**
1) Can I add text/scss to my MIME types? I am using the Mac terminal looking at apache's MIME types and don't see any reference to scss or sass extensions

2) Why would my styles not be applied at all?

3) Not a priority but if anybody has the answer, how do I customize Foundation sites beyond the default styling?

**

### Explanation:

**
I am not doing anything fancy, just trying to style my webpage and learning Sassy CSS. I tried to customize the _.settings.scss file given in the foundation setup but the changes weren't loading and now it doesn't even use the default styling. In the Chrome dev tools I see no styles applied or referenced and the page looks like simple HTML.

I am getting the following **errors:** in Dev tools for Chrome

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:63342/MMM/scss/app.scss' 
because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not a supported 
stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
2news-magazine.html:1 

Refused to apply style from '..../foundation/scss/foundation.scss' 
because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not a supported 
stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
news-magazine.html:1 

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:63342/MMM/scss/app.scss' 
because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not a supported 
stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

**HTML:**

---

```
 <title>MMM</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet"  
 href="./bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation.scss" />
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="./scss/app.scss" />

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css="  
 href="./bower_components/foundation/css/foundation.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css="  
 href="./bower_components/foundation/css/foundation-icons.css" />
 <script src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js" ></script>
 <script src="./bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bower_components/font- 
 awesome/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome.min.css"/>
 <script 
 src="./bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js"> . 
 </script>
 <script src="./bower_components/foundation/js/
    foundation/foundation.equalizer.js">
 </script>



 </head>
```

**

---

**Settings File **

```
$include-html-panel-classes: $include-html-classes;

// We use these to control the background and border styles
$panel-bg: scale-color(#FFFFFF, $lightness: -5%);
$panel-border-style: solid;
$panel-border-size: 1px;
$callout-panel-bg: scale-color($primary-color, $lightness: 94%);

//// We use this % to control how much we darken things on hover
$panel-border-color: scale-color($panel-bg, $lightness: -11%);

//// We use these to set default inner padding and bottom margin
$panel-margin-bottom: rem-calc(20);
$panel-padding: rem-calc(20);

//// We use these to set default font colors
$panel-font-color: #FF3548;
$panel-font-color-alt: $white;

$panel-header-adjust: true;
$callout-panel-link-color: #000000;
$callout-panel-link-color-hover: scale-color($callout-panel-link-color, 
$lightness: -14%);
```

Thank you for your help in advance. Please let me know if I need to include anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Sass is not a clientside solution and you need some Sass / SCSS compiler and then have to use the generated css files.

Also 3 questions in one are two too much.

Here are some tools:

https://getcrunch.co/
http://koala-app.com/
https://prepros.io/

And IDEs like VSCode can also compile (using extensions).

Comment: Hi Thank you! So using compass is not compiling? And when compiled, the MIME type errors will go away thus allowing styling?

Comment: compass is a Sass compiler but you need the result of the compilation, the generated css files.